# How to use jQuery ContextMenu to have 2 different menus one above the other inside a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

Using [jQuery ContextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) plugin or pure Javascript, is it possible to use **2 different context menu** (first on parent and the second on the child element)?

In my snippet I would like to open the **first menu only on right click** (on the table row) and open the **second menu only on left click** of the button (inside my row).

I set `trigger: 'left'` only for the button however when I left click on it both menus are shown as you see here:

```js
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
           copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        }
    });
    
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-two', 
              trigger: 'left',
        items: {
            "new": {name: "New", icon: "new"},
            "open": {name: "Open", icon: "open"}
        }
    });  
});
```

```css
table{width:300px;height:100px}
tr {background:#222;color:#fff}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="context-menu-one">
            <td>
                <button class="context-menu-two">Left click</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a method to prevent the first menu to be shown when I click on the button?

**1st UPDATE**

Based on Aswin Kumar answer, the two menus are displayed correctly individually but, as you can see from my gif below, if you try to:

1. click the button
2. move the mouse on hover the menu
3. move the mouse outside the menu
4. close the menu clicking the left mouse button

In this case the user is not able to close the menu (4th point). Is there a work around for close the menu on left click outside the menu?

[image]

Comment: as far i know you can have multiple menus on one page but opening another context menu inside another and that too on `left-click` dont think so, you can have sub-menus inside the menu up to 3 levels or maybe more but not like that. Do you want to open sub-menus under the opened context menu ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for the info, yes I believe I should find something different...no I don't need a sub-menu but thanks again

Comment: but still i couldnt get the idea behind why you are trying to do such thing, why open a context with left-clicking on a menu item on another context menu.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam because I need the user to be able to right click over the entire table row to open a menu and in the same time to be able to left click a button (inside the row) to open a different menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using contextMenu's `show` event (cancellable) and jquery's `hasClass` to verify the target element. Along with the help of `z-index`

**UPDATE**

4.close the menu clicking the left mouse button `(fixed)`

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
      $('.context-menu-one').contextMenu('hide');
      $('.context-menu-two').contextMenu('hide');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var m = "clicked: " + key;
      window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    events: {
      show: function() {
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('context-menu-two')) {
          return false
        }
        $('.context-menu-two').first().contextMenu('hide');
      }
    },
    autoHide: true,
    items: {
      "edit": {
        name: "Edit",
        icon: "edit"
      },
      "cut": {
        name: "Cut",
        icon: "cut"
      },
      copy: {
        name: "Copy",
        icon: "copy"
      },
      "paste": {
        name: "Paste",
        icon: "paste"
      },
      "delete": {
        name: "Delete",
        icon: "delete"
      },
      "sep1": "---------",
      "quit": {
        name: "Quit",
        icon: function() {
          return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-two',
    trigger: 'left',
    autoHide: true,
    items: {
      "new": {
        name: "New",
        icon: "new"
      },
      "open": {
        name: "Open",
        icon: "open"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px
}

tr {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff
}

.context-menu-two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.context-menu-root {
  z-index: 3!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Custom-jQuery-Context-Menu-Plugin-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="context-menu-one">
      <td>
        <button class="context-menu-two">Left click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But try this: 1. click the button 2. mouse hover the menu 3. move the mouse outside the menu. In this case the user is not able to close it. Is there a work around for close the menu on left click outside the menu?

Comment: It's not working. 1. left click on the button 2. mouse hover the menu 3. move the mouse outside the menu 4. click the left mouse button to close it. The 4th point doesn't work.

Comment: @SimonOrro It's behaving correctly, [`hideonsecondtrigger`](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#hideonsecondtrigger) feature is not available in this version. Since you asked Its updated with a workaround

Comment: For me the version of the ContextMenu plugin is irrelevant, what interests me is that it works correctly. Please check the updated question with a gif.

Comment: @SimonOrro Check now. I think the major issues are gone. Am I right?